# Symfony form type add form type validation not working

Tags: php, forms, symfony, validation

I'm using Symfony 3.3 and added a form type to another form type:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
$builder->add('document', DocumentType::class);
...
}
```

All form fields are handled correctly, but the validation is not working/not done. I had tried to add validation_groups to the form type, but still did not change anything. When I use the `DocumentType` alone, validation is working correctly.

How can I add validators when I add a form type to another form type?

Do I have to set parameters when I `add` the `DocumenType`?

Would be nice if I got your thoughts!

Thanks and best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `'cascade_validation' => true,`

```
$builder->add('document', DocumentType::class, [
    'cascade_validation' => true,
]);
```

or

```
$resolver->setDefaults(array(            
    'cascade_validation' => true,
));
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! I had to set `@Assert\Valid` in the entity to the property "document". [Symfony form valid](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html)

Answer (score 0):

- How can I add validators when I add a form type to another form type?

You can try this...

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;

```
$builder->add('document', DocumentType::class, [
    'constraints' => new NotBlank(),
]);
```

more details [Here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/without_class.html#adding-validation)

if this is not your purpose then try 
[Custom Validation Constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html)

- Do I have to set parameters when I add the DocumentType?

No you don't have set parameters  when add the DocumentType

check this official link [Custom Form Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html)